# What is the better way to use Optional in conditions?

Tags: java, java-8

I have already written the code, but the thing is I feel there could be better way to write the below code,

This must be possible only from Java 8

```
private User getUser(String userId) {
    Optional<User> optionalUser = userDAO.getUserById(userId);
    if(optionalUser.isPresent())
        return optionalUser.get();
    throw new UserDefinedException("User not present");
}
```

I expect to write the above in one line

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `orElseThrow`, which will return the value if present or throw the specified exception if not:

```
private User getUser(String userId) {
    return userDAO.getUserById(userId)
                  .orElseThrow(() -> new UserDefinedException("User not present"));
}
```

Comment: Might be better `new UserDefinedException("User not present - " + userId)`